# Proof of insurance to enter Vietnam

Tags: insurance, vietnam

I have read that, in order to enter Vietnam for a 2 week trip, I have to have medical insurance for Covid with a minimum coverage of $10,000. Finding such an insurance is not difficult. I have already found many companies online that can offer me such an insurance. However, what I'm wondering about, is how I will be able to *prove* that I have such insurance to the Vietnamese border authorities.

Of course, I could just show an insurance sheet, but there are thousands of insurance companies around the world and such sheets should be easy to forge. So how will the border authorities know the sheet is legit, and issued by a trustworthy insurance company?

Comment: I was in Uruguay last week which also has a Health Insurance requirement for entry.  I had to fill out an online health form where I had to certify that I had Health Insurance, but no actual documents needed to be submitted or where checked

Comment: If they are sufficiently suspicious about the validity of the certificate, they will contact the issuer. You’ll probably have a long wait while they do it, too

Comment: That goes for just about any fact relevant to border checks and entry. Some documents (in particular passports) now have security features that make them difficult to forge but most do not (airline tickets, proof of income, accommodation, insurance, etc.), nothing really surprising here. It just raises the hurdle a little and could in principle be investigated. It could also be pure theater, something someone came up as a compromise without thinking too much about enforcement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border authority will trust you if you provide a print out of insurance. If it is forged, then its a crime. If detected, you will be charged and you may have to pay fine or possible jailtime.

I think its deterrent enough for a document like this.

Furthermore, you will have to pay for treatment and isolation expenses out of your own pocket, if you get covid, which will be much more than what you have "saved".

Answer (score 2):

I was in Vietnam a few weeks ago.  While I had an insurance certificate, it was never checked by airline staff or immigration/customs at all. Your mileage may vary.